# Issues manipulating data from within a function

Tags: r, function, matrix, functional-programming, mixture-model

I have several data frames structured like this:

```
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
```

I am using the mclust package to fit mixture models. There are several things I need to do iteratively on each of these data frames, and I find myself feeling very unorganized (and with a full environment) when trying to do them multiple times. So I have been writing the function below to make things easier, and produce the output I need to see. Basically, I need to be able to specify the data (`dat`) the columns I want it to use (`cols`), the number of mixture components I want it to use (`g`), and the model name I want it to use (`modname`). The steps of what I am trying to accomplish with the function are as follows: 
- fit the model, make density and classification plots, 
- get bootstraped parameter estimates using non-paremetric and weighted likelihood resampling
- compare the two bootstrap methods in the figure
*use the non-parametric bootstrap for the remainder 
- make a data frame that combines the original data with a new column showing which cluster the observation was assigned to (return via knitr::kable)
- collect the mean, bootstrapped standard error, and number of observations in each cluster; use them to make a plot that shows the average +/- SE for each variable connected by cluster, also return these values via kable 
- Return kables showing how many observations are in each cluster that correspond with each grouping variable

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mclust)
library(knitr)
fitclust <- function(dat, cols, g, modname){
  set.seed(123)
  mod <- Mclust(dat[,cols], G=g, modelNames = modname, initialization = list(hcPairs = randomPairs(dat[,cols], seed = 123)))
  plot(mod, what = "classification")
  plot(mod, what = "density")
  rand <- kable(data.frame(GV = c("Region", "State", "Loc"),RandIdx = rbind(adjustedRandIndex(dat$Region, mod$classification), adjustedRandIndex(dat$State, mod$classification),adjustedRandIndex(dat$Loc, mod$classification))))
  boot <- MclustBootstrap(mod, nboot = 2, type = "bs")#2 for now to speed it up
  wlboot <- MclustBootstrap(mod, nboot = 2, type = "wlbs")

  modinfo<- kable(lapply(c(mod$parameters[1:2], mod$parameters$variance[4:7]), data.frame))
  probs<-data.frame(mod$z)
  colnames(probs) <- paste0("C", 1:ncol(probs))
  probs <- kable(probs)

  boot.ci <- summary(boot, what = "ci") 
  wlboot.ci <- summary(wlboot, what = "ci")
  par(mfrow = c(1,2), mar = c(4,4,1,1)) 
for(j in 1:mod$G) { 
  print(plot(1:mod$G, mod$parameters$mean[j,], col = 1:mod$G, pch = 15, 
       ylab = colnames(dat[,cols])[j], 
       xlab = "Mixture component", 
       ylim = range(boot.ci$mean,wlboot.ci$mean), 
       xlim = c(.5,mod$G+.5), xaxt = "n")+ 
  points(1:mod$G+0.2, mod$parameters$mean[j,], col = 1:mod$G, pch = 15)+ 
  axis(side = 1, at = 1:mod$G)+ 
  with(boot.ci, errorBars(1:G, mean[1,j,], mean[2,j,], col = 1:G))+ 
  with(wlboot.ci, errorBars(1:G+0.2, mean[1,j,], mean[2,j,], col = 1:G, lty = 2))) } 
  par(mfrow = c(3,2)) 
  plot(boot, what = "pro") 
par(mfrow = c(1,1))

newdat <- cbind(dat, cluster = mod$classification)
a <-
  newdat%>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.numeric)%>%
  dplyr::group_by(cluster)%>%
  summarise_all(mean)%>%
  pivot_longer(-c("cluster"), names_to = "Vars", values_to = "mean")
b<-
as.data.frame(cbind(cluster=1:mod$G, t(summary(boot, what = "se")$mean)))%>%
   pivot_longer(., -c("cluster"), names_to = "Vars", values_to = "SE")
newdat<-dplyr::mutate(a, "SE" = b$SE)

ClustComp<-
ggplot(a, aes(x=Vars, y=mean, group=factor(cluster))) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cluster)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width = .1)+
  ggtitle("Mean by cluster") +
    expand_limits(y=0) +                        # Expand y range
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:20*4) +         # Set tick every 4
    labs(x = "Var", y = "Cluster Average")+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.justification=c(1,0),
          legend.position=c(1,0))               # Position legend in bottom right
RegCt<-
kable(newdat%>%
  dplyr::select(Region,cluster)%>%
  group_by(cluster,Region)%>%
  count())
StateCt<-
kable(newdat%>%
  dplyr::select(State,cluster)%>%
  group_by(cluster,State)%>%
  count())
LocCt<-
kable(newdat%>%
  dplyr::select(Loc,cluster)%>%
  group_by(cluster,Loc)%>%
  count())
newdat <- kable(newdat)
a <- kable(a)
output <- list(rand, modinfo, probs, newdat, a, RegCt, StateCt, LocCt, ClustComp)
return(output)
}

fitclust(dat= dat1, cols = 5:9, g=3, modname="EEV")
```

When running this, you will get an error that says `Error: Column`SE`must be length 35 (the number of rows) or one, not 30`. 
Strangely, when trying this function with my real data, it works just fine with some combinations of columns(`cols`) and mixture components (`g`), although I haven't found a combination between that works in this reproduceable example. For instance, I have a data frame with 13 columns and 289 rows (columns 1:6 are factors, and columns 7:13 are numeric). Assuming that data frame is named `dat1`, the function works when I use `fitclust(dat=dat1, cols = 7:13, g=5, modname="VEI")`, but not when I use `fitclust(dat=dat1, cols = 7:12, g=5, modname="VEI")`. I believe that this issue has to do with the way I am transposing the matrices when the function creates `a` and `b`. How could I have written this differently to fix this bug? 
Also, when I extract the information for `modinfo` in the function, how could I retain the names associated with those list components (mod$parameters; pro, mean, sigma, scale, shape, and orientation), so that they are labeled in the output?

Comment: Your working and not working lines are exactly the same. Please advise and post actual error messages as *not working* is not specific.

Comment: @Parfait apologies I fixed my typo and added the error message.